# javascript in iOS webview not working in app's code, but does work in remote debugger

Tags: javascript, ios, remote-debugging

I am running some javascript code via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString on a webview.  There's no output when I try to log the results of the js in the code, unless I run something simple like "document.title", which works.

But using the remote debugger in Safari, I can run the exact same code with the console and get the correct results.

Any ideas as to what could be going on here that would prevent the javascript from working in the app?  Obviously the code is fine, since it works in the debugger.  Are there restrictions on running javascript in webviews in the app?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you try to log the results to the console? Back when I did it, there was no remote debugging so I basically used http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/ to send the objects from JS back to objective C and investigated the results there.

Comment: I'm just using NSLog, which I would assume is ok since it correctly logs something like document.title.

Comment: Ok, now you lost me. Did you put NSLog into the javascript code?
Can you please post some source code of what you are trying?

Comment: No, sorry. I meant that I was using NSLog in my app's code.  The console that I was referring to in the original post was from the remote debugging window, which just lets you run javascript via the app's webview.  So when I was running the javascript code in the remote debugger, it worked as expected.  But having the exact same code in the source of the app (executed with stringByEvaluating...etc.) and running the app, the javascript code does not work.  So I'm stumped as to where it's going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems getting the Javascript/Native interfaces to work, so some of my learnings:

- As soon as the Javascript interpreter hits an error (no matter what, missing semicolon or whatever) it just silently stops working and will NOT continue.
- Sounds stupid, but put `@"alert(1);"` into your `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to see if it does work at all.
- Keep the commands send via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString short; create javascript 
  methods and call into them from the native code, e.g.
  `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"doalliwant();"];` 
  instead of piping a 100 kb file through that interface.
- Use something like https://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/ to send data from Javascript to Obj-C code. By that, you can achieve a minimum of logging in your Javascript. (By sending it to Obj-C and logging it there)
- Use remote debugging for your UIWebview, WWDC Session "600 - Debugging UIWebViews and Websites on iOS" describes that. You can get it via the iOS developer program website. To enable the basics, go for Settings->Safari->Advanced and enable Web Inspector. Connect your device to the Mac, start XCode and your app in the debugger. Start Safari on the Mac. Open Safari's settings, in the last tab enable the developer's menu. Restart Safari. In the new Developer's menu you should now see the name of your iOS device where you can select your app and start debugging.

Hope that should get you started...